# How can I access to didSet of a Type in general use case in Swift?

Tags: swift

I am working on a custom type called **UIL** stand for **Unique Identifiable Label**, here is my code:

```
struct UIL: Equatable {

    init?(labelValue: String) {

        if checkLabelAvailability(for: labelValue) {
            
            identifiableLabelCollection.insert(labelValue)
            self.labelValue = labelValue
            
        }
        else {
            return nil
        }
        
    }

    var labelValue: String
    
    static func ==(lhs: UIL, rhs: UIL) -> Bool {
        return lhs.labelValue == rhs.labelValue
    }
    
}
```

---

```
var identifiableLabelCollection: Set<String> = Set<String>()


func checkLabelAvailability(for label: String) -> Bool {
    return !identifiableLabelCollection.contains(label)
}
```

And this my use case:

```
var myLabel: UIL? = UIL(labelValue: "Hello, world")

if let unwrappedValue: UIL = myLabel {
    print("myLabel:", unwrappedValue.labelValue)
}

myLabel = UIL(labelValue: "Hello, world!")

if let unwrappedValue: UIL = myLabel {
    print("myLabel:", unwrappedValue.labelValue)
}


myLabel = UIL(labelValue: "Hello, world")

if let unwrappedValue: UIL = myLabel {
    print("myLabel:", unwrappedValue.labelValue)
}
else {
    print("cannot use it! myLabel is now nil!")
}
```

And this the results:

> myLabel: Hello, world

> myLabel: Hello, world!

> cannot use it! myLabel is now nil!

The issue is here that I should remove the string of replaced UIL from collection to make it available for next access, I can put codes in didSet of **myLabel** for this goal, but I want make this happen undercover and make developer free to thinking about it. I want access the didSet of type UIL and then I remove that label string from collection if the oldValue and newValue are deferent than each other.

Comment: Why not use willSet or didSet for the property labelValue?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson: I think there is a miss understanding, didSet of labelValue in UIL would not called when we update value of myLabel.

Comment: Ok I see now what you mean

Comment: I can put my needed codes in didSet of myLabel, but as i said i must repeat this for each variable type UIL for cover all and it is ugly coding.

Comment: You don’t have any control of the variable myLabel from inside the UIL struct since it lives in a different scope so this is not doable.

Comment: It is nil because you already have `labelValue` = `"Hello, world"` in the set of them. At the first time you added it and when try to add the second time the same `"Hello, world"` returns you nil `else { return nil }` in your custom init method

Comment: @matsotaa: I made the codes and I know why it is nil! you can read my question if you like again! I did NOT asked why it is nil! Did I asked why `labelValue` is nil? I read my question again for myself and I did NOT found the part that I asked why it is nil, instead I found this part, I think it is nice to mentioning for you as well: "How can I access to didSet of a Type in general use case in Swift?"

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating a new `UIL` each time, why not update the `labelValue`  directly? Then you can have a `didSet` on `labelValue`, which will be triggered anytime an existing instance of `UIL` is replaced. For new labels it won't matter, because they aren't "decommissioning" an existing text yet.

`UIL` would then look like this:

```
struct UIL: Equatable {

    var labelValue: String {
        didSet {
            if oldValue != labelValue {
                identifiableLabelCollection.remove(oldValue)
            }
        }
    }

    init?(labelValue: String) {
        if checkLabelAvailability(for: labelValue) {
            identifiableLabelCollection.insert(labelValue)
            self.labelValue = labelValue
        }
        else {
            return nil
        }
    }

    static func ==(lhs: UIL, rhs: UIL) -> Bool {
        return lhs.labelValue == rhs.labelValue
    }
}
```

And your use cases would look like this:

```
var myLabel = UIL(labelValue: "Hello, world")

if let unwrappedValue: UIL = myLabel {
    print("myLabel:", unwrappedValue.labelValue)
}

myLabel?.labelValue = "Hello, world!"

if let unwrappedValue: UIL = myLabel {
    print("myLabel:", unwrappedValue.labelValue)
}


myLabel?.labelValue = "Hello, world"

if let unwrappedValue: UIL = myLabel {
   print("myLabel:", unwrappedValue.labelValue)
}
else {
    print("cannot use it! myLabel is now nil!")
}
```

Let me know if I misunderstood what you're trying to do here - I would have asked for clarification in a comment, but my account is too new and doesn't allow commenting yet.

Comment: Also your code does not work! you need to correct your answer to this: `if (oldValue != labelValue) { identifiableLabelCollection.remove(oldValue); identifiableLabelCollection.insert(labelValue) }`

Comment: Good point about checking to make sure the value is different.

I never implied that you didn't know how to upvote an answer, I was just explaining why I created an answer instead of just commenting. I don't think it matters how long either of us has had an account, but rather how much experience we have writing Swift/iOS code and how we interact and share that experience with others :)

What is the reason why you want to initialize a whole new instance each time rather than updating labelValue?